# In UnityScript, why does GUI not get called within hit on collider?

Tags: user-interface, touch, unityscript

I'm trying to print out text when a user touches a sprite, however, even though I get no errors when building and running the code, the code refuses to printout the text and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. Please help me understand why it does not print.
It prints the debug text when I touch the sprite, but not the GUI text with total.

This is the code:

```
#pragma strict

function Start () {


OnGUI();
}

function OnGUI(){
//var total = 0;

    //GUI.Label( myRect, total.ToString() ); // Displays "10".
    //GUI.Label( myRect, "" + bullets ); // Displays "10".
   // GUI.Label(Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),"Total:"+total);
}
//function Update () {

//}
var platform : RuntimePlatform = Application.platform;

function Update(){

    if(platform == RuntimePlatform.Android || platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer){
       if(Input.touchCount > 0) {
         if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began){
          checkTouch(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
         }
       }
    }else if(platform == RuntimePlatform.WindowsEditor){
       if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
         checkTouch(Input.mousePosition);
       }
    }
}

function checkTouch(pos){
var total = 0;

    var wp : Vector3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(pos);
    var touchPos : Vector2 = new Vector2(wp.x, wp.y);
    var hit = Physics2D.OverlapPoint(touchPos);

    if(hit){
    GUI.Label(Rect(0,0,Screen.width,Screen.height),"Total:");
       Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
       hit.transform.gameObject.SendMessage('Clicked',0,SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);


      //total = total +1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your sprite have a collider setup on it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a gui item outside the OnGUI Method. You need to set a boolean to turn on the label. 
Something along these lines.

```
OnGUI(){
if(labelbool)
    GUI.Label ....
}

check(){
labelbool = true;
}
```